# How to use solver add-in with binary constraints

Tags: excel, vba, binary, constraints, solver

I'm trying to find the maximum possible value of a cell which contains a formula.  The result of the formula is dependent upon some binary values.  I've created an example.  It's a much simpler workbook, but it has all the same problems.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHlsc.png)

In the ScreenShot:

- Column A contains values of x which are either 10 or 1
- Column B contains values of y which are either 10 or 1
- Column C contains values of Binary which are either 0 or 1
- Column D contains values of Selection which are based on a simple formula which returns the value of x (column A) if Binary (column C) has a value of 0, and returns the value of y (column B) if Binary (column C) has a value of 1.  eg. the formula in cell D2 is: =IF(C2=0,A2,IF(C2=1,B2,0))
- Cell E2 is the sum of the selections (column D).

I've written three macros to find the maximum value in cell E2 by:

- Varying all 10 values of Binary (eg. cells C2:C11)
- Varying the first two values of Binary (eg. cells C2:C3)
- Varying the first value of Binary (eg. cell C2 only)

Each time I run a macro, I reset the binary values to original (eg. as shown).

Macro "Maximise10" should return a value of 100:

```vb
Sub Maximise10()
    Dim CellToChange, CellToSolve As String

    Sheets("Example").Select
    CellToChange = "C2:C11"
    CellToSolve = "E2"
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Precision:=0.1, Convergence:=0.5
    SolverOK SetCell:=Range(CellToSolve), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range(CellToChange), Engine:=3
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range(CellToChange), Relation:=5
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        
End Sub
```

Macro "Maximise2" should return a value of 28:

```vb
Sub Maximise2()
    Dim CellToChange, CellToSolve As String

    Sheets("Example").Select
    CellToChange = "C2:C3"
    CellToSolve = "E2"
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Precision:=0.1, Convergence:=0.5
    SolverOK SetCell:=Range(CellToSolve), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range(CellToChange), Engine:=3
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range(CellToChange), Relation:=5
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        
End Sub
```

Macro "Maximise1" should return a value of 19:

```vb
    Sub Maximise1()
    Dim CellToChange, CellToSolve As String

    Sheets("Example").Select
    CellToChange = "C2"
    CellToSolve = "E2"
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Precision:=0.1, Convergence:=0.5
    SolverOK SetCell:=Range(CellToSolve), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range(CellToChange), Engine:=3
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range(CellToChange), Relation:=5
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        
End Sub
```

I only get results with the "evolutionary" method.  In the solver options, I've tried adjusting:

- Iterations
- Precision
- Scaling
- AssumeNonNeg
- PopulationSize
- MutationRate
- MaxSubproblems

The code above has provided the best results yet, but the outcome is less than satisfactory.

- The "Maximise1" sub should be the easiest problem to solve because there should only be two options.  Excel regularly locks up (eg. not responding) when I run this macro with different options.  If it doesn't lock up, Solver continues to run without finding a solution.
- The "Maximise2" sub should be relatively easy because there are only four options to be considered.
- Despite having binary constraints, solver consistently considers non-integer values in column C.

I would very much appreciate some assistance to determine how to best configure the solver add-in to ensure it only considers integer values to  determine a maximum value in the fastest, most efficient manner possible.

Comment: The Solver explains the differences between the solver engines, and as you are controlling a result with an if() then the Simplex LP will of course not be suitable. The other two engines cope with nonlinear and discontinuous functions, so Evolutionary is the correct choice. I would set up separate sheets with the stated conditions you suggest 10 and 2, then run the solver by hand and read the solver reply about the quality of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition:

```
=IF(C2=0,A2,IF(C2=1,B2,0))
```

is equivalent to

```
=IF(C2=0,A2,B2)
```

Since Solver's Simplex method doesn't like IF functions, we can re-write this as:

```
=(1-C2)*A2+C2*B2
```

This is a linear function of the variables, so the Simplex method will work. Though change the Integer Optimality option to be 0%.
In the example, the optimal solution is an objective function value of 100.

Comment: Thankyou.  This advice/direction has worked a treat.  Your assistance is very much appreciated.  Regards, Scott.